# import QtQuick.Controls 2.0 not working - QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component

Tags: qt, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols, qtquickcontrols2

I have an app that its project generated using `CMake` in `Qt5.7`,
so when `import QtQuick.Controls 2.0` application failed to load with the following error:

> plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtQuick.Controls": Cannot load
>   library
>   C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\qml\QtQuick\Controls.2\qtquickcontrols2plugind.dll: The specified module could not be found.

CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Qt\\Qt5.7.0\\5.7\\msvc2015")
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON) 
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON) 
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Qml) 
find_package(Qt5Quick) 
find_package(Qt5QuickControls2)

...

add_executable(MyApp ${SRC} ${HEADER} ${RESOURCES})

target_link_libraries(MyApp
Qt5::WinMain    
Qt5::Core   
Qt5::Qml    
Qt5::Quick  
Qt5::QuickControls2     
)
```

The `DLL` file loaded in visual studio output:

```
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\qml\QtQuick.2\qtquick2plugind.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\qml\QtQuick\Controls.2\qtquickcontrols2plugind.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\qml\QtQuick\Controls.2\qtquickcontrols2plugind.dll'
```

Comment: Which files do you have in `C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\msvc2015\qml\QtQuick\Controls.2`? It looks like it's trying to find the debug version of the plugin, but does your Qt installation have it available?

Comment: Yes, it the dll file is there in the path and loaded in visual studio (I see in the intellisense, its symbols loaded) but fails to load app.

Comment: For some reason it unloads the plugin right away? I don't know what could cause that. What happens if you open the plugin with Dependency Walker? Is this a pre-built Qt installation from an installer? If so, does the Qt Quick Controls 2 Gallery example work?

Comment: it unloads because of QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component, so I'll use DependencyWalker, so the Gallery example works well when build and run from QtCreator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution, The problem is `QtQuick.Controls 2.0` depends on `QtQuick.Templates 2.0` module so I have copied its dll to output directory and it runs successfully.

required DLLs (for Debug version):

```
Qt5QuickTemplates2d.dll
Qt5QuickControls2d.dll
```

required DLLs (for Release version):

```
Qt5QuickTemplates2.dll
Qt5QuickControls2.dll
```

Comment: Is this something Qt's CMake integration can/should handle automatically? Is it normal that you have to list the whole dependency chain by hand? Or is it perhaps a missing dependency declaration somewhere in QQC2?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that QtGui and QtXmlPatterns are not explicitly listed either, so it must resolve dependencies to some degree.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Ubunty try to install qml-module-qtquick-controls2

```
sudo apt install qml-module-qtquick-controls2
```

Comment: `qml6-module-qtquick-controls` for Qt6

Answer (score 2):

On Windows Qt provides deployment tool which automatically scans all Qt and QML dependencies:

```
%QTDIR%\bin\windeployqt.exe your_app.exe --qmldir your\qml\files
```

[See the Qt documentation:](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html)

> The tool can be found in QTDIR/bin/windeployqt. It takes an .exe file
>   or a directory that contains an .exe file as an argument, and scans
>   the executable for dependencies. If a directory is passed with the
>   --qmldir argument, windeployqt uses the qmlimportscanner tool to scan QML files inside the directory for QML import dependencies. Identified
>   dependencies are then copied to the executable's directory. The
>   hardcoded local paths in Qt5Core.dll are furthermore replaced with
>   relative ones.